# Update text in sunburst bilevel partition

Tags: javascript, d3.js, sunburst-diagram

I've a sunburst bilevel partition with text inside arcs but when I change level the text from other level are visible and sometimes the text from the level top are not delete. Anyone can help me?

Here's my code for create path and text inside and the functions when I zoom in top level or when I zoom in dwon level.

```
        var path = group.append("path")
                .attr("d", arc)
                .style("fill", function(d) {
                    return d.fill;
                })
                .each(function(d) {
                    this._current = updateArc(d);
                })
                .on("click", zoomIn);

        var textEnter = group.append("text")
                .style("fill-opacity", 1)
                .style("fill", "white")
                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                .attr("dy", ".2em")
                .attr("transform", function(d) {

                    var angle = x(d.x + d.dx / 2) * 180 / Math.PI - 90;
                    return "translate(" + (arc.centroid(d)) + ")rotate(" + (angle > 90 ? 0 : 0) + ")";
                }).on("click", zoomIn);

        textEnter.append("tspan")
                .attr("x", 0)
                .text(function(d) {
                    return d.name;
                });
        textEnter.append("tspan")
                .attr("x", 0)
                .attr("dy", "1em")
                .text(function(d) {
                    return d.depth ? d.name.split(" ")[1] || "" : "";
                });

        function zoomIn(p) {
            if (p.depth > 1) {
                p = p.parent;
            }
            if (!p.children)
                return;
            //alert(p.parent.name+" parent");
            //alert(p.name+" p");
            zoom(p, p);
        }

        function zoomOut(p) {
            if (!p.parent)
                return;
            //alert(p.parent.name+" parent");
            //alert(p.name+" p");
            zoom(p.parent, p);
        }

        // Zoom to the specified new root.
        function zoom(root, p) {
            //textEnter.transition().attr("opacity", 0);
            if (document.documentElement.__transition__)
                return;

            // Rescale outside angles to match the new layout.
            var enterArc,
                    exitArc,
                    outsideAngle = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 2 * Math.PI]);

            function insideArc(d) {
                return p.key > d.key
                        ? {depth: d.depth - 1, x: 0, dx: 0} : p.key < d.key
                        ? {depth: d.depth - 1, x: 2 * Math.PI, dx: 0}
                : {depth: 0, x: 0, dx: 2 * Math.PI};
            }

            function outsideArc(d) {
                return {depth: d.depth + 1, x: outsideAngle(d.x), dx: outsideAngle(d.x + d.dx) - outsideAngle(d.x)};
            }

            center.datum(root);

            // When zooming in, arcs enter from the outside and exit to the inside.
            // Entering outside arcs start from the old layout.
            if (root === p)
                enterArc = outsideArc, exitArc = insideArc, outsideAngle.range([p.x, p.x + p.dx]);

            path = path.data(partition.nodes(root).slice(1), function(d) {

                return d.key;
            });

            textEnter = textEnter.data(partition.nodes(root).slice(1), function(d) {

                return d.key;
            });


            // When zooming out, arcs enter from the inside and exit to the outside.
            // Exiting outside arcs transition to the new layout.
            if (root !== p)
                enterArc = insideArc, exitArc = outsideArc, outsideAngle.range([p.x, p.x + p.dx]);

            d3.transition().duration(d3.event.altKey ? 7500 : 750).each(function() {

                path.exit().transition()
                        .style("fill-opacity", function(d) {

                            return d.depth === 1 + (root === p) ? 1 : 0;
                        })
                        .attrTween("d", function(d) {
                            return arcTween.call(this, exitArc(d));
                        })
                        .remove();

                textEnter.data(partition.nodes(root).slice(1))
                        .transition()
                        .duration(500)
                        .attr("transform", function(d) {
                            return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";
                        });

                //d3.selectAll("path").remove();
                //d3.selectAll("text").remove();

                path.enter().append("path")
                        .style("fill-opacity", function(d) {
                            return d.depth === 2 - (root === p) ? 1 : 0;
                        })
                        .style("fill", function(d) {
                            return d.fill;
                        })
                        .on("click", zoomIn)
                        .each(function(d) {

                            this._current = enterArc(d);
                        });

                textEnter.enter().append("text")
                        .style("fill", "white")
                        .attr("transform", function(d) {
                            var angle = x(d.x + d.dx / 2) * 180 / Math.PI - 90;
                            return "translate(" + (arc.centroid(d)) + ")rotate(" + (angle > 90 ? 0 : 0) + ")";
                        }).attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                        .text(function(d) {
                            return d.name;
                        }).on("click", zoomIn);

                path.transition()
                        .style("fill-opacity", 1)
                        .attrTween("d", function(d) {
                            return arcTween.call(this, updateArc(d));
                        });
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try adding a line inside the transition block, after

```
path.exit().transition()...
```

to remove the exiting labels, like:

```
textEnter.exit().remove();
```

For example, there's something similar going on here, where `labels` is the variable to watch: http://bl.ocks.org/tomalrussell/2c8c5e24bf614f80e3bc#d3.sunburst.js